# Bumper on 2008 Nissan Versa hatchback

Tags: nissan, bumper, versa

[image]Any advice on fixing a bumper or lifting a sagging one for a 2008 Nissan Versa hatchback? Looking for a cheap solution. Thanks!

Comment: What have you checked in terms of the existing fixings? Are they missing, bent or broken?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you could provide detailed pictures with further explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, it would help us tremendously!

Comment: @SolarMike The clips are broken and there was some kind of wiring that seemed to run through the top and bottom. It looks like this wiring is cut because I don’t see it anymore.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I edited the post with a picture, thank you!